# Exercise 5 of section 6 of Diestel's book

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Exercise 5 mentioned:

View the group of circulations on a graph with values in $\mathbb Z_2$ as a vector space. Find  a space(edge space or cut space ...)to which  it is isomorphic.

I can see how the group of circulation is a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$, but I cannot find  a vector space which is isomorphic to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is a circulation on $G=\langle V,E\rangle$ with values in $\Bbb Z_2$. For any $e=xy\in E$ we have $f(e,x,y)=-f(e,y,x)=f(e,x,y)$; in other words, $f$ doesn’t distinguish $\overrightarrow{e}$ from $\overleftarrow{e}$, and we can simply treat $f$ as a function from $E$ to $\Bbb Z_2$, i.e., as an edge set of $G$.

Of course not every edge set of $G$ necessarily arises in this way: $f$ has the property that $f(v,V)=0$ for all $v\in V$, i.e., that for each $v\in V$,

$$\sum\{f(vx):vx\in E\text{ and }x\ne v\}=0\;.$$

A sum of $k$ elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ is $0$ if and only if $k$ is even, so an edge set $F$ of $G$ corresponds to a $\Bbb Z_2$-circulation if and only if each vertex of $G$ is incident with an even number of edges in $F$. To put it a little differently, $F$ correponds to a $\Bbb Z_2$-circulation on $G$ if and only if every vertex of $\langle V,F\rangle$ has even degree.

That should very strongly suggest a suitable candidate amongst the various spaces associated with $G$.